# Python `collections.defaultdict` for the same class

Tags: python, trie, defaultdict

I try to use a Trie data structure for some coding problem.
For each node in a trie, you typically put a a list of reference of its children.
So, I thought about using defaultdict to create a default empty trie node if some children does not exists in a lookup.
However, I don't know how to use defaultdict to refer to the class that enclose it.

I tried two methods, which were both failed. The following is what I tried.

```py
from dataclasses import dataclass
from collections import defaultdict

@dataclass   
class TrieNode():
    is_word = False
    children = defaultdict("TrieNode")
```

The code above produce

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 2, in <module>
  File "<stdin>", line 4, in TrieNode
TypeError: first argument must be callable or None
```

```py
@dataclass   
class TrieNode():
    is_word = False
    children = defaultdict(TrieNode)
```

The above will produce

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 2, in <module>
  File "<stdin>", line 4, in TrieNode
NameError: name 'TrieNode' is not defined
```

My question is about how do you use `defaultdict` to implement this elegantly.
Thank you very much in advance.

Comment: why not use a list?

Comment: Or maybe start from the code in the wikipedia entry on `trie`?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Your second approach with `children = defaultdict(TrieNode)` is closer to correct, since `defaultdict` needs the constructor for `TrieNode` in order to populate it with `TrieNode`s - the other approach passes a string where a callable is expected. Your problem is being caused by the fact that you are accessing the name `TrieNode` before the class has finished being created, giving the `NameError`. To fix this you can use `children = defaultdict(lambda: TrieNode())`. This way, the name `TrieNode` is only looked up when the lambda function is called.

However, this leads us to another bug! Take this code:

```
class Thingy:
  pass
  
@dataclass
class MyDataclass:
  my_thingy = Thingy()
```

A line `my_thingy = Thingy()` inside a dataclass definition will create an instance of `Thingy`, and use it as the default value for the `my_thingy` attribute - all new instances of `MyDataclass` will use this same instance of `Thingy` unless they specify a different value in the constructor:

```
class Thingy:
  def __init__(self):
    print("a Thingy is born")

print("Thingy has been defined")
  
@dataclass
class MyDataclass:
  my_thingy = Thingy()

print("MyDataclass has been defined, but no instances")
a = MyDataclass()
b = MyDataclass()
print("Are they the same instance?", a.my_thingy is b.my_thingy)
```

Output:

```
Thingy has been defined
a Thingy is born
MyDataclass has been defined, but no instances
Are they the same instance? True
```

Notice how `"a Thingy is born"` is only printed once, during the definition of the `MyDataclass` class, not when a new instance of `MyDataclass` is created.

For a trie, you want every node to have its own dictionary of children, and with this approach, modifying the children dictionary for one node will modify it for them all because all their dictionaries would be the same object. I would reccomend you use [`dataclass.field`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/dataclasses.html#dataclasses.field) to create a new dictionary for each `TrieNode`, like so:

```py
from dataclasses import dataclass, field
from collections import defaultdict

@dataclass
class TrieNode:
  is_word = False
  children: defaultdict[str, 'TrieNode'] = field(
      default_factory=lambda: defaultdict(TrieNode)
  )
```

Comment: Smart, thank you for such a decent solution.

Comment: Can you elaborate why using `children = defaultdict(lambda: TrieNode())` will make every node shares the same dictionary? It doesn't seem obvious to me why.

Comment: @cakraww I've edited my answer, does it make sense now?